# Does typesafe's config support custom converters?

Tags: java, guice, typesafe-config

## Context

I want to automatically inject configuration items using Guice. My configuration framework is typesafe's config.

```
public class MyObject {
  @Configuration("value") int value;
}
```

To do that, I wrote an annotation.

```
// Annotations skipped, but correct
public @interface Configuration {
  String value();
}
```

And I wrote a module. This module checks for all types to inject, then allows the injection itself.

```
public class ConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {
    final Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
    class ConfigurationMembersInjector<T> implements MembersInjector<T> {
      private final Field field;
      ConfigurationMembersInjector(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
        field.setAccessible(true);
      }
      @Override public void injectMembers(T t) {
        try {
          String key = field.getAnnotation(Configuration.class).value();
          field.set(t, config.getXxxx()); // what to write?
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    }
    class ConfigurationTypeListener implements TypeListener {
      @Override public <T> void hear(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<T> typeEncounter) {
        for (Field field : typeLiteral.getRawType().getDeclaredFields()) {
          if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Configuration.class)) {
            typeEncounter.register(new ConfigurationMembersInjector<T>(field));
          }
        }
      }
    }
    bindListener(Matchers.any(), new ConfigurationTypeListener());
  }
}
```

## Question

How do I automatically convert a configuration item to a specific yet unknown type? Is there a way to say "I want this item converted as this type"? Also, is there a way to "register" custom converters?

Or else, do I have to write my own conversion mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.3.0 (released on April 16th, 2015), there exists a [`ConfigBeanFactory`](http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigBeanFactory.html), which is the closest thing to what I ask. A bit late for my project but happens to do the trick.

Comment: Does it support binding nested config to nested java objects?

Comment: @user1870400 Yes, it does, if those objects follow some simplified JavaBeans conventions: no-arg constructor; public setter and getters for each property, or the property is of a type supported by a `Config.getXXX()` method. This means the declared type of the property must be the concrete type to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to what you're trying to do is to use a [Classpath scanner](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to scan for your custom annotation (which I assume is a [Binding Annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations)) and then bind your configuration values to those types annotated with those annotations.

This is the exact approach I take in developing my library: [Typesafe Config Guice](https://github.com/racc/typesafeconfig-guice), which binds config values from a [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) file to annotated parameters and fields.

Comment: This doesn't answer the basic question: "Does typesafe's config support custom converters?"